# Wikipedia Dump xml file convert into text in python

Tags: python

How can I convert a wikimeadia dump xml file into text in python. is there any package in python?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what dump you have, from the post you are trying to convert the web content and read the elements and write in to a file using python.

better use website scrape using requests and bs4 objects:

```
#Getting data from website - scrape 
import requests, bs4

#Getting HTML from the wikipedia page
url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors"
req = requests.get(url)

#Create a bs4 object
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html5lib")

element = soup.select('.mwe-math-element')

print(element)
#You can save the required content to a file by manipulating the content in element list
```

Comment: I have XML file from the link: https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwikisource/20190220/enwikisource-20190220-pages-articles-multistream.xml.bz2